# Why is foo.hasOwnProperty('__proto__') equal to false?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

```
var foo = {
  bar : 5
}
```

Why is `foo.hasOwnProperty('__proto__')` equal to `false`?

It can't be from any object in the prototype chain higher up, because it is specific to this very object.

**EDIT**:

Some answers say that it is on `Object.prototype`.

But I don't understand how that makes sense. My question is not where it is, but why it isn't where it should be.

For example:

```
var a = new Foo();
var b = new Bar();
// Foo inherits from Bar
```

So shouldn't `a.__proto__` be equal to `b.__proto__`?

Since they're both reading off `Object.prototype` ?

Comment: It's just that `Object.prototype.__proto__` has a getter function which returns differently when called on different objects. For example, if you run `Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'self', {get: function(){return this}})`, you can call `.self` on different objects and you will get different results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, `__proto__` is inherited from `Object.prototype`:

```
foo.hasOwnProperty('__proto__')              // false
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('__proto__') // true
```

And according to [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto#Description),

> There is nothing special about the `__proto__` property.  It is simply
>   an accessor property -- a property consisting of a getter function and
>   a setter function -- on [Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).

As you say, intuitively it can seem that, since `__proto__` is intrinsically related to each object, it should be an own property.

But it isn't like this. Instead, `Object.prototype.__proto__` has a getter function which returns differently when called on different objects.

You can obtain something similar if you run

```
Object.defineProperty(
    Object.prototype,
    'self',
    {get: function(){return this}}
)
```

Now you can call `.self` on different objects and you will get different results.

Also note this behavior isn't exclusive of `__proto__`. For example, the `id` property of an HTML element isn't an own property neither:

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.id = 'foo';
el.hasOwnProperty('id');                // false
Element.prototype.hasOwnProperty('id'); // true
```

<sup>(Webkit browsers don't follow the spec and `el.hasOwnProperty('id')` is `true`)</sup>

Comment: so... you're saying that `__proto__` is not a member of an object instance, but rather it's a member of `Object.prototype`  that gets/sets the super secret special [[Prototype]] property of the current instance? So when you ask for `__proto__` set/get, it needs to traverse the whole prototype chain to the very root to get the getter/setter and only THEN change `this's` actual `this.[[Prototype]]`? this is whack. No wonder they suggest Object.getPrototypeOf -- you skip the dynamic dispatch to the root, and get the getter in constant time.

Comment: @Dmitry Where can I find out that `Object.getPrototypeOf` runs at constant time?