# How to understand "hasOwnProperty" and "__proto__" in Js?

Tags: javascript, v8

In ECMAScript,there is not `__proto__` of an object:

```
 Array.hasOwnProperty('prototype')   //true
 var arr = new Array()
 arr.hasOwnProperty('__proto__')     //false
```

then, we can find:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(arr)
```

Output:

```
length:{value: 1, writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: false}
__proto__:Object
```

So, I am confused:
 Does `arr` has his own property `__proto__`?

When I try to do follow things:

```
arr.unshift("2")
```

Where does Js engine find `unshift` method?

Is there any information let Js engine find `unshift`?

Comment: `unshift` is a property of `Array.prototype`.

Comment: @PHPglue but `arr` has no property named `__proto__`, how does JsEngine find `Array.prototype.unshift` from `arr` ?

Comment: `var arr = [];` is a new instance of an Array. Arrays have methods they inherit from `Array.prototype`, but they are not its own property. Array properties should be numeric indexes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is foo.hasOwnProperty('\_\_proto\_\_') equal to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295785/why-is-foo-hasownproperty-proto-equal-to-false)

Answer (score 2):

> Where does Js engine find unshift method?

On `Array.prototype`, from which `arr` inherits. There is an *internal* prototype chain link, often called [[prototype]], on every object. You can access it using [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf).

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(arr) == Array.prototype
```

> So, I am confused: Does arr has his own property `__proto__`?

No, `__proto__` is a setter/getter that is inherited from `Object.prototype`, it's not an **own** property. (You can find `"__proto__" in arr`, though). And [it's deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36061819/1048572). Best forget about it.

> Why does `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(arr)` output a `__proto__`?

Because the console uses this name to denote the internal prototype link. `getOwnPropertyDescriptors` returns an object, which naturally inherits from `Object.prototype`. Nothing special. You will find it in the empty object `{}` as well.