# Where does the information stored in an instance that tells the JS Engine this object's constructor?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, v8

```
>>function Foo(){this.a = "a"}
>>var foo = new Foo()

>>Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(foo)
a: {value: "a", writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}
__proto__: Object

>>foo.hasOwnProperty("__proto__")
false
```

I understand line 8's result.

But I think there is some information stored in the foo that tells JS Engine which function create foo.

Maybe foo has a hidden property tell JS Engine Foo creates foo, or maybe there is a list stored in the memory that record Foo creates foo.

What's the fact? 
How does JS Engine know foo is an instance of Foo but no Array?

Comment: Well `Object.getPrototypeOf(foo).constructor == Foo`, but other than that why do you think the JS engine would be interested in which function created the instance?

Comment: What  has `arr.hasOwnProperty("__proto__")` to do with this, there's no `arr` in your code? Does't that relate to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48984407/1048572)?

Comment: @Bergi sorry,it is Opps

Comment: Still I thought I already had answered why `__proto__` is not found as an own property, it's the same for `foo` as it was for `arr` in the previous question. So what else do you need to know?

Comment: As I know,`foo` only has one property`a`, foo does not have `__proto__`or `constructor`.when I try to use foo.toString() or other methods, how does JS Engine find those methods?

Comment: Because they are inherited! Do you understand how [prototype inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) works?

Comment: @Bergi Back to the first question:how does JS Engine calculates `foo.__proto__=== Foo.prototype`?  `foo` does not have a property which named `__proto__`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165819/discussion-between-wind-west-and-bergi).

Comment: Every object has a hidden internal property containing the data that `__proto__` reports;`__proto__` itself happens to be an inherited accessor property, but every object "knows" what its prototype is.

Answer (score 0):

`foo.constructor` will tell you what was the constructor function that was used to create the object

Comment: but `foo.hasOwnProperty('construtor') `  output `false`

Comment: @WindWest its not directly in `foo`, but in its prototype